# Finding usage of Tempdb by user databases

Tags: sql-server, database, tempdb

In my SQL Server, I have 9 user databases and I would like to find out which user database is using how much resources in `tempdb`, which database is using more and which less, and furthermore, I would like to store the records.

While investigating the issue, I found all solutions on tempdb auto-growth tracking.

Since `sys.dm_db_session_space_usage` and `sys.dm_db_task_space_usage` DMVs don't keeps historical data, how can I get database-wise tempdb usage information?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Some useful info [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6183/1186), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/19870/1186), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/61703/1186), and [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/dude-who-owns-that-temp-table).

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom Logging Table: First, create a table in a database where you want to store the  tempdb usage information.
Set Up Extended Events: You can use SQL Server's Extended Events to capture the tempdb usage for each database
Schedule the Data Retrieval: Create a SQL Server Agent job or use another scheduling mechanism to run the data retrieval script periodically, such as every minute, hour, or as needed.

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.

Comment: I also tried Extended Events. But all events are related to file size change or auto-growth or page latch.
But I need very raw data that which user database is using how much in tempdb regularly, may be for a range of one week.